# Apache web serving serving incomplete pages

Tags: apache, vpn, cisco

I have an Apache web server which several sites are connecting to.
From most sites it is accessible and serves content properly (sites being remote and connected via Cisco VPNs), but there is one site, where the server will serve an incomplete page when requested for the login page of the application we are running.

It does not matter what this application is I guess since it is working fine on 10 other sites, just not on this one.

I am getting exactly 907 bytes of the page (the last 907 bytes out of 4000 bytes).
Wireshark reports that the server response is not the first packet and that there is a packet missing before the capture started. Needless to say I waited minutes to start the browser after the capture started so there is no way a packet really was lost because of Wireshark still trying to start up.

Any idea where I look to resolve this?

As it works everywhere it seems to indicate something goes wrong on the network. Where would I look for such an awkward behaviour where 3000 bytes of a web server response get swallowed?

Comment: The first thing to check is the Apache logs. Do they provide any clues?

Answer (score -1):

There is no indication on the Apache logs that anything special has occured on the failed pages.